# How to deploy application with QT5

Tags: deployment, qt-creator, qt5

So I have made GUI frontend for latex with QT5 using QT creator. The application works fine, but I'm unable to deploy it. The deploy option in build is grayed out. I have also tried following [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html) guide but I can't even configure my QT to use static linking. I was able to configure the source, but when I try to run mingw32-make sub-src, it says nothing to do here.

I downloaded QT from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads) using the link Qt 5.0.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.7, 823 MB). I have also downloaded microsoft visual studio express for Windows 8 to get tools required for building c++.

I also tried to install mingw32 manually. I have also installed Strawberry perl, because one guide told me to do that, but that did nothing.

Comment: Well, first you need to decide on a compiler. In your question you mention both MinGW or VC++. I would recommend linking the Qt libraries dynamically and ship the Qt libraries that you use with your application. Finally, you may want to include the compiler C++ runtime libraries with your application as well. If you still experience problems, please try to be more specific.

Comment: Okay, no I have removed all other compilers and left only mingw. I have also linked my Qt libraries dynamically, and tried copying all needed libraries to release folder. I have checked with Dependencies walker that all required libraries / dll can be found, but the .exe still won't run. Dependencies walker gives warning about 64bit dll's. So maybe may problem is that my windows 8 is 64bit and my qt is 32bit. Can this be the problem? If this is the problem, how can I compile my code to be 64bit? I could't find 64bit qt for windows, only for linux.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem. There was one .dll. Reason why I didn't find it earlier was that my application did not need it by itself, but one of libraries I used was dependaple from it. The missing .dll was icuuc49.dll.